# What's the type for "half" (binary16) in C#?

Tags: c#, value-type

I'm working in a context where nVidia GPU's are implied, which leads me to using the "half" (binary16, low precision floating-point number) type. However, I don't know to which type this translates in C#. Any idea?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half_precision_floating-point_format

Comment: As far as I know there isn't any mainstream non-shader language with direct support for this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Prior to .NET 5.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.half?view=net-5.0), .NET doesn't support "half" as a [basic type](http://www.solidcode.co.uk/Content/Programming/Tutorials/Basics/BasicTypes.aspx). However, there are [libraries](https://sourceforge.net/projects/csharp-half/) providing conversion routines.

Comment: It is available now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.half?view=net-5.0.

Answer (score 17):

[.NET 5 includes `System.Half`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.half?view=net-5.0) to represent the IEEE 754-2008 `binary16` floating point data type. There's no C# type for it (yet), though.